Prove that $\exp(A\cdot\nabla)\exp(F\cdot\nabla)\exp(-A\cdot\nabla)=\exp(e^{A\cdot\nabla}F\cdot\nabla e^{-A\cdot\nabla})$
In a book I am reading, the author is stating that the following equation holds for any Lie operator (or any linear operator, more generally):
$\exp(A\cdot\nabla)\exp(F\cdot\nabla)\exp(-A\cdot\nabla)=\exp(e^{[A\cdot\nabla,\,\circ]}\,F\cdot\nabla)$,
where $[X,\circ]$ is the adjoint of $X$, such that $[X,\circ]\; Y = [X,\,Y] = XY - YX$.
One step of this proof is the question in the title, from which we can apply a similarity transform to get to the final expression with $e^{[A\cdot\nabla,\,\circ]}$ in the exponent.
I can prove the latter the similarity transform $e^X Y e^{-X} = e^{[X,\circ]}Y$ by constructing functions $U(t)=e^{tX}Ye^{-tX}$ and $V(t)=e^{t[X,\circ]}Y$ and showing their initial values and derivatives agree.

Taylor-expand the exponential in the middle and use the fact that $e^XY^ke^{-X} = (e^XYe^{-X})^k$.
